# Open Edx IOError: [Errno 20] (draggabilly.pkgd.js)

Tags: python, vagrant, devstack, edx, paver

I installed OpenEdx with Vagrant, 
 
When I try to launch `paver devstack studio` or `paver devstack lms` with `--fast` or not, I got one error:
`IOError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform/common/lib/xm
odule/xmodule/js/common_static/js/vendor/draggabilly.pkgd.js'`

I try a lot of tricks I could see on StackOverflow, but nothing work.
(I tried the "dealing-with-line-endings-and-symlinks-under-windows" trick)

This is my cygwin logs when I try : http://pastebin.com/ZcJqZU06

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen this error many times and I can tell you it is definitely a symlink error.

Sadly I could never find a reliable solution so what I do now while working with openedx under windows is that I remove the shared folder where the edx-platform is installed.

Search for and comment this lines in your Vagrantfile:

```
config.vm.synced_folder "#{edx_platform_mount_dir}", "/edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform",
  create: true, owner: "edxapp", group: "www-data"

config.vm.synced_folder "#{edx_platform_mount_dir}", "/edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform",
  create: true, nfs: true
```

This will allow you to run the platform under windows, but since you are not sharing the directory where the code is, then it a lot more complicated to edit and change to your will. For that I recommend switching to an OS that does a better job with symlinks.

Answer (score 0):

1. copy file in folder `edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform/common/static`
2. then create folder name `common_static` in `edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform/common/lib/xmodule/xmodule/js`
3. paste file in folder `common_static`

Hope this can solve your problem